# Collaborate on an Excel workbook integrated in a web app

Tags: javascript, asp.net, excel, asp.net-web-api, javascript-api-for-office

In my company we work with excel a lot, and I have been writing excel macros in VBA to automate anything that can be automated, recently we needed to collaborate on some sheets and we used google sheets for that.
I then wrote a script that automatically protects cells when they're edited by someone and makes him the only allowed editor, with a button to clear protections when done. (+ for google)

We would rather work with Excel so I found out that it was possible to host a web app and use the JavaScript API to embed Excel worksheets with custom HTML and CSS, an example can be found [here](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/data_visualization/excelmashup/index.htm) (VBA is not supported online)

Would it be possible to embed an Excel worksheet into a hosted web app, then allow different users to collaborate inside the web app, then automatically protect a cell when edited and make its editor the only one allowed to edit, then save the settings until next session?

By using for example the web app user directory or Microsoft Exchange Server for authentication.

Comment: It is possible to do it in PHP, I am currently working on this. I will update this post when done.